Is it possible to limit concurrent Lambda instances fed from an SQS queue to only allow 1 at a time?
I have an SQS queue which passes AppFlow events through to a Lambda. For various reasons I'd like to limit the concurrent Lambda instances to only allow 1 at a time if possible. Originally thought this might be achieved with reservedConcurrentExecutions: 1 on the Lambda and maxConcurrency: 2 on the SQS queue. But the documentation says:

When using the two features together, you must set the function
reserved concurrency higher than the maximum concurrency on the SQS
event source mapping to prevent throttling.

But the minimum value of maxConcurrency is 2... does this mean there isn't a way to limit the concurrent Lambdas to 1 at a time via AWS configuration?

Try it by just using Reserved Concurrency. It should satisfy your needs if the Lambda functions are reasonably fast compared to the rate of incoming messages.

Thanks @JohnRotenstein, that's what I'm doing and it seems to be working fine so far in a test environment. Was just worried about possible issues once it goes into PROD given there may be more AppFlow events coming in from unpredictable activity in Salesforce.

Using Reserved Concurrency (with a low number) will lead to throttles. Throttled invocations are in fact failed invocations - so they will go back to the SQS queue and eventually land in the DLQ. Means, you'll have a lot of invocations (cost!) and have to deal with the queue not performing well. That's why the introduction of maxConcurrency was a great feature, since the concurrency is controlled by the queue, not the Lambda. But you're right - 2 is the minimum (which is explained with SQS being a distributed system).
